# Kubernetes: Using same service(Rabbitmq) for both HTTP and WS traffic

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq, kubernetes

I am trying to set up rabbitmq cluster within kubernetes. Clients can connect to Rabbitmq using amqp protocol rides on TCP and webclients using websockets. As mentioned in [WebSocket support](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket) for kubernetes, I need to add websocket services against "**nginx.org/websocket-services**" annotation for ingress configuration. In this case rabbitmq acts as both websocket and non-websocket service.

Will the configuration work for amqp clients loadbalancing if I give rabbitmq service name against "**nginx.org/websocket-services**" ?

In short, can a service be both non-ws and ws at sametime?

**EDIT [ 05-02-2018 ]**

It seems there is a [different](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/tcp) flow for TCP loabalancing. I implemented that. Atleast the routing part is happening but I am not sure about load-balancing of TCP, I need to debug further on that part.

And there is one more [reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#websockets) for websocket loadbalancing and seems to say "**No special configuration required**".

Kiran

Comment: _In short, can a service be both non-ws and ws at sametime?_ have you tried creating two separate `RMQ-WS` and `RMQ-AMQP` Services, but have each select the same pods and point to the same `targetPort` (or, uh, different targetPort if rabbitmq is listening differently, of course); that should allow you and the Ingress controller to be on the same page, but still have traffic arrive as rabbitmq wishes

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, Thanks for the reply. I haven't tired this approach. And I really don't know how to do this either. I will try this. Please see my edit.  I found a reference for ws loadbalancing. According this reference, it doesnot talk about using "nginx.org/websocket-services" and i am really confused now. I am not sure which link to follow.

Comment: Since it's waaaay too long for a comment, but isn't an answer, [this link](https://pastebin.com/WWVEetFR) is what I meant about double Service pointing to the same Pod; that said, I think your update about using TCP seems reasonable, also

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel,  Thanks for the code. Now I got what you meant. I will try that.